# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, devise

I have been stuck up with this exception.I am using rails 4.2.5.1 and ruby 2.3.0. I am creating a model using devise in rails. I have override the devise create method. I am getting error in postgres as  PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint.I want the ID to be created with the help of parameters i am passing. ID is not getting created. As am new to rails am getting stuck up for hours now.

**Request
Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"SAiVJEULEa7RsieW+OTW1a/946f2xVbhA/sZWWn3KdX1Wt0Ozx+tq6eQfhTpaAJ+4Cxu2DMnPfqd0Vcle7ow0w==",
 "employee"=>{"email"=>"safi123@gmail.com",
 "first_name"=>"sss",
 "last_name"=>"dddnjnfj",
 "phone_number"=>"9944253677",
 "alternative_phone_number"=>"9659392682",
 "alternative_email_id"=>"dd@gmail.com",
 "date_of_joining"=>"12-02-2015",
 "date_of_birth"=>"03-02-1999",
 "status"=>"Active",
 "gender"=>"M",
 "blood_group"=>"A +"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_employee!


before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |employee_params|
        employee_params.permit  :first_name, :last_name, :blood_group, :phone_number, :gender, :date_of_birth, :email, :alternative_email_id, :status, :date_of_joining, :alternative_phone_number
      end
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |employee_params|
        employee_params.permit :first_name, :last_name, :blood_group, :phone_number, :gender, :date_of_birth, :email, :alternative_email_id, :status, :date_of_joining, :alternative_phone_number
      end
    end

end
```

**Registrations Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end
 def create
  @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      redirect_to :action => :new
    else
      render 'new'
    end
    @employee.save  
  end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :blood_group, :phone_number, :gender, :date_of_birth, :email, :alternative_email_id, :status, :date_of_joining, :alternative_phone_number)
    end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

**Database schema :**

I can understand the ID is not generated and it is not stored in the database. What is the problem here? Can anyone explain me what is the mistake am making?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the employee record twice. That may be the problem, please save only once.I have given the action please check.

```js
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      redirect_to :action => :new
    else
      render 'new'
    end
   /* Here you had saved again. */
  end
```

Your Employee params,

```js
def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :blood_group, :phone_number, :gender, :date_of_birth, :email, :alternative_email_id, :status, :date_of_joining, :alternative_phone_number)
end
```

Now you will get the id through params and it will be saved.

Comment: Hai, did you try this?

Comment: yes.. I tried that.. but it is throwing other exception undefined method `present' for #<Employee:0x007f7021adfca8> Did you mean? present? presence

Comment: ID has to be created by passing the parameters. Right? here we are manually giving ID to be stored..

Comment: You said that you want Id to be created with the params so I have answered like this.If not  will change. Please revert the downvote.

Comment: And i want to create ID with the help of the params i am passing.

Comment: You also have another error in your code, you saved two times. Now I updated the answer please check.

Comment: Okay, Someone has downvoted it. They should see this.